# Resolving core data relationship raising SIGABRT error

Tags: swift, core-data

I am relearning the swift core data basics using the swift playground.

I am writing out core data long-hand to write a simple playground app where

> One `Company` has many `Employees`

I am constantly getting an error:

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.

When it comes to saving a relationship between a company and a single employee, but I'm not sure why its being raised.

My code now follows:

```
// Swift playground code
import CoreData

class NotificationListener: NSObject {
    @objc func handleDidSaveNotification(_ notification:Notification) {
        print("did save notification received: \(notification)")
    }
}

let listener = NotificationListener()
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(listener, selector: #selector(NotificationListener.handleDidSaveNotification(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextDidSave, object: nil)


// Define managed object
let model = NSManagedObjectModel()

//: [Entities]

let companyEntity = NSEntityDescription()
companyEntity.name = "Company"

let employeeEntity = NSEntityDescription()
employeeEntity.name = "Employee"
employeeEntity.indexes = []

//: [Attributes]

let companyNameAttribute = NSAttributeDescription()
companyNameAttribute.name = "name"
companyNameAttribute.attributeType = NSAttributeType.stringAttributeType
companyNameAttribute.isOptional = false

let countryAttribute = NSAttributeDescription()
countryAttribute.name = "country"
countryAttribute.attributeType = NSAttributeType.stringAttributeType
countryAttribute.isOptional = false

let employeeNameAttribute = NSAttributeDescription()
employeeNameAttribute.name = "name"
employeeNameAttribute.attributeType = NSAttributeType.stringAttributeType
employeeNameAttribute.isOptional = false

let ageAttribute = NSAttributeDescription()
ageAttribute.name = "age"
ageAttribute.attributeType = NSAttributeType.integer16AttributeType
ageAttribute.isOptional = false

// Relationships

let companyRelationship = NSRelationshipDescription()
let employeeRelationship = NSRelationshipDescription()

companyRelationship.name = "company"
companyRelationship.destinationEntity = companyEntity
companyRelationship.minCount = 0
companyRelationship.maxCount = 0
companyRelationship.deleteRule = NSDeleteRule.cascadeDeleteRule
companyRelationship.inverseRelationship = employeeRelationship

employeeRelationship.name = "employees"
employeeRelationship.destinationEntity = employeeEntity
employeeRelationship.minCount = 0
employeeRelationship.maxCount = 1
employeeRelationship.deleteRule = NSDeleteRule.nullifyDeleteRule
employeeRelationship.inverseRelationship = companyRelationship

companyEntity.properties = [companyNameAttribute, countryAttribute, employeeRelationship]
employeeEntity.properties = [employeeNameAttribute, ageAttribute, companyRelationship]

model.entities = [companyEntity, employeeEntity]

// Create persistent store coordinator
let persistentStoreCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel:model)

do {
    try persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSInMemoryStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: nil, options: nil)
} catch {
    print("error creating persistentStoreCoordinator: \(error)")
}

let managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.mainQueueConcurrencyType)
managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = persistentStoreCoordinator

// Companies
let companyABC = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Company", into: managedObjectContext)
companyABC.setValue("ABC Ltd", forKeyPath: "name")
companyABC.setValue("United States", forKeyPath: "country")

let companyDelta = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Company", into: managedObjectContext)
companyDelta.setValue("Delta", forKeyPath: "name")
companyDelta.setValue("Canada", forKeyPath: "country")

let tom = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Employee", into: managedObjectContext)
tom.setValue("Tom", forKey: "name")
tom.setValue(22, forKey: "age")
tom.setValue(companyABC, forKey: "company") // <<-- Throws error

let sarah = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Employee", into: managedObjectContext)
sarah.setValue("Sarah", forKey: "name")
sarah.setValue(41, forKey: "age")
sarah.setValue(companyDelta, forKey: "company")   // <<-- Throws error



func save(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {

    // Save context
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("error saving context: \(error)")
    }

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Company")

    var results: [NSManagedObject] = []

    do {
        results = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

        print ("\n#\(results.count) records found\n")

    } catch {
        print("error executing fetch request: \(error)")
    }

    print("results: \(results)")
}

save(context: managedObjectContext)
```

The issue comes when it attempts to save one employee:

```
let tom = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Employee", into: managedObjectContext)
tom.setValue("Tom", forKey: "name")
tom.setValue(22, forKey: "age")
tom.setValue(companyABC, forKey: "company")
```

The error is raised when attempting to set the companyABC as the relationship for the `tom` object.

The objective is to make `Tom` and employee of `companyABC`

I believe the relationship has been created properly.

But I am unsure of what is causing the error.

Thus, my query is: How can I resolve this error?

With thanks

Comment: Ok, I am going to be the boring one but isn't the simplest way forward to create a regular project with Core Data support rather than using the playground?

Comment: I was just hoping to keep it seperate for now so I can understand the basics without the overhead of maintaining a whole xcode project.   I understand what you're asking and yes, I agree with it.  I just wanted to do some basic stuff first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
tom.setValue(Set([companyABC]), forKey: "company")
...
sarah.setValue(Set([companyDelta]), forKey: "company")
...
```

Because in this case, if you'd generate a class model with XCode from a CoreData Graph, it would have generate the objects where the property `company` is a `(NS)Set`. <strike>I think it should be written somewhere in the CoreData documentation, but `set` is unfortunately a too common word.</strike> Edit, found it.

From the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/KeyConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH30-SW1):

> The Destination pop-up menu defines what object (or objects) is returned when the relationship is accessed in code. If the relationship is defined as to-one, a single object (or nil if the relationship can be optional) is returned. **If the relationship is defined as to-many, a set is returned** (or again, nil if the relationship can be optional).

Comment: That seems to work.  I appreciate the prompt feedback.  I wasn't aware I had to set the relationship property as a `set`, but I thank you for the assistance

Comment: @zardon Doc spec added ;)